# How to sum a cell across several worksheets using indirect cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Assume, I have Worksheets `A-Z`.

I want to SUM cell, `C21`, across several worksheets (e.g. A-Z).

I've tried this formula:

=`SUM('A:Z'!C21)`

However, now if I add rows in sheets A-Z, that moves the values of `C21` to `C24` the formula stays the same, i.e. the formula stays `SUM('A:Z'!C21)`, whereas it should now be `SUM('A:Z'!C24)`.

I believe I can solve this with an indirect cell reference. Something like:

`=SUM('A:Z)'!(Indirect(CEll("address,C21))))`

However, this returns an error ("There is a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula?....").

Does anybody know why? And is the right approach or is there a better approach?

Comment: If you have all the workbooks open and then make a change, Excel should automatically update the cells too. Indirect formulas won't work across multiple workbooks though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I meant worksheets, not workbooks, perhaps you misread. I tried updating across all the sheets, yet the formula keeps referring to the old cell (c21) instead of the new (c24)

Answer (score 1):

**This simple Formula can solve your issue:**

`=SUM(B:Z!C21)`

**Or, if you want to use INDIRECT with SUM 
  then do the following:**

- Anywhere in Sheet, enter Sheet name and 
  put one heading like in my sample data 
  below is, **SheetName**.

  [image]
- Select Entire Range including Header, and 
  from **Formula Tab**, click **Create from 
  selection** and select **Top Row** option, 
  finish with **Ok**.

[image]

- Enter this formula in any blank Cell

  `=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&SheetName&"'!"&"C21:C21")))`

*Adjust Sheet Name, Cell references and Range Name in Formula as needed.*